# Converting RAW NEF files to PNG/TIff - why is the converted PNG file 6x larger than the NEF file and TIFF 9x larger

Tags: raw, tiff, png

I'm trying to convert NEF files to PNG or some other lossless format.

Using Preview/Imagemagick, the 10MB NEF file is converted to 60-70MB png file or 95MB tiff file.

Also tried converting to HEIC but it only allows 8bit depth, the resulting files are relatively small, 7MB.

Comment: TIFFs are always a lot bigger than NEFs. Mine go from 30MB to 140. I've no real idea why PNGs should be larger.

Comment: What is your final goal that requires that you save the NEF file into another format? [Archive](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archive)? Display on the web?

Comment: Move to phone gallery

Comment: Why do you need 16bit PNG on your phone?

Comment: Not sure. Thought maybe the quality would be better ‍♂️

Comment: This is not a complete answer - we'd need more information on the exact formats - but a couple factors would be that the NEF is 12- or 14-bits per pixel, and only a single value at each sensor site. Going to 16-bit is a 14-33% change per value. Then, the PNG/TIFF have three values per pixel (RGB), so that's an additional 3X expansion. Then there's the difference in compression algorithms - not sure exactly what NEF uses, but PNG and TIFF have several options, including uncompressed....

Comment: @AvnerBarr What do you intend to do with the images once they're on your phone?

Comment: I just want a format that i can use in my iphone in my gallery

Comment: You really don't need lossless on a phone, really. jpgs will do. You could also drop them to half size or smaller & no-one will ever notice. I always save out my finished work [as well as saving the originals as psd] as jpg - full size @100% qual, & 33.3% size, 60% qual for mobile. That's about 150KB per image & no-one will ever spot the difference on a phone.

Comment: @AvnerBarr If your iPhone supports heic, I'd go with that.

Comment: At 7MB per image, translated blind from NEF, I'd go JPG. You could get nearly 50x more pics on there with no appreciable difference. The blind translations are going to be rubbish anyway.

Comment: The PNG "compression" is designed for computer generated graphics, it doesn't produce significant results  on photos.